# What are the different techniques to jam in a crack?

Tags: climbing, terminology, technique, crack-climbing

I have been told that climbing cracks is very much a methodical procedure. Especially in places like Yosemite and Indian creek, where the cracks can be the only feature of the rock that can be used to climb up. There is a distinct set of techniques employed to jam your finger/hands/arms/... in the crack, which can be "ordered" by crack width. Not absolute width, at it always depends on the climbers finger/hand/arm/... thickness, just to sort the techniques from narrowest to widest. Some techniques I know of but that are certainly not complete: ring lock, hand jam, fist jam, hand&fist stack, chicken wing, ...

What I am looking for is an ordered list of these crack climbing techniques.

If the names aren't self evident, a short explanation is welcome, but don't got into detail - many of these techniques probably warrant their own question.

Comment: I made my answer community wiki, please add to that instead of creating a dozen different answers.

Answer (score 3):

To start with,

- Tips
- Fingers
- Ringlock
- Handjams (thumbs up, thumbs down, cupped hand)
- Fistjams
- Hand & Fist stack
- Fist stack
- "Chicken wing"
- Arm bar

whole body (chimney):

- frog (feet against back wall, knees aginst front wall)
- sitting (back against back wall, feet against front wall)
- stemming (left foot/hand against one wall, right foot/hand against other)

If you have more, just add them to the list.

Comment: http://rockandice.com/how-to-climb/how-to-crack-climb/ these are all relevant

Comment: @Fistbeard Feel free to add any missing ones into the answer

Comment: Way too lazy, that's why I threw it in as a comment :D